# How to assign $data to css class?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of string values. I am looping through the array like this,

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<div data-bind="css: {'dkblue': true, $data: true }">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The div ends up like this, `<div class="dkblue data">` instead of actual value of $data (and dkblue).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In KO 2.2, the `css` binding can be used to apply a class dynamically.  This means that you can either do:

```
<div class="dkblue" data-bind="css: $data">
```

or

```
<div data-bind="css: 'dkblue ' + $data">
```